# How to set the default value to sharepoint date time field programmatically?

Tags: 2013, spfield, default-value

I want to set the default value for the sharepoint's built-in field `ArticleStartDate` programmatically. But I am unable to do so. My code is as follows:

```
SPField articleDate = currentWeb.Fields[FieldNames.ArticleStartDate];
if (articleDate != null)
{
    articleDate.DefaultValue = Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(DateTime.Today);
    articleDate.Update(true);
}
```

I debugged the program and found the error at the statement `SPField articleDate = currentWeb.Fields[FieldNames.ArticleStartDate];` after executing this statement control directly goes to the `Catch()` statemenets and displays the error message only `false`. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following code,

```
SPFieldDateTime articleDate =(SPFieldDateTime ) currentWeb.Fields[FieldNames.ArticleStartDate];
```

Where,

[SPFieldDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfielddatetime_members.aspx) - Represents a field that contains date and time values.

Comment: It is working perfectly, as per your answer Sir, but thing I want to achieve is to make the today's date selected. The image is [here](http://i.imgur.com/lSomxpY.png), and what I am getting is [here](http://i.imgur.com/OweQGBT.png)